# Almost increasing sequence in Go: how to loop avoiding index out of bound?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, go

So I am trying to learn Go by doing some algorithm challenges, and the one I am currently on is called almost increasing sequence.

The instruction looks like:

> Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.

> - For `sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1]`, the output should be
>   `almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = false`;

> There is no one element in this array that can be removed in order to get a strictly increasing sequence.

> - For `sequence = [1, 3, 2]`, the output should be
>   `almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = true`.

> We can remove 3 from the array to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 2]. Alternately, we can remove 2 to get the strictly increasing sequence [1, 3].

> The function must return true if it is possible to remove one element from the array in order to get a strictly increasing sequence, otherwise return false.

I have finished this in Typescript already, it was not hard. But I am trying to write it again in Go, but I found it is kinda tricky to avoid `index out of range` error in Go. Here is my code so far:

```
func almostIncreasingSequence(a []int) bool {
    var count int = 0

    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
        if a[i] <= a[i-1] {
            count++
            if (a[i] <= a[i-2]) && (a[i+1] <= a[i-1]) {
                return false
            }
        }
    }

    return count <= 1
}
```

This is what I literally converted what I wrote in Typescript and it works fine with Typescript, but as you can easily notice from my Go code `index out of range` error occurs when as it iterates, `if a[i] <= a[i-1]`.

Are there any tricks to compare an element at index `i` and `i - 1` or `i + 1` avoiding `index out of range` error when write code in Go?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try something like `if i-1 >= 0 && a[i] <= a[i-1]`

Comment: and for the nested if try `if (i-2 >= 0 && a[i] <= a[i-2]) && (a[i+1] <= a[i-1])`

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a trick. You are looping from `0` (first element) through the length of the array minus one, or upper bounds. When `i == len(a) - 1` then `a[i+1]` is going to exceed the length of the array. If there are only 3 items in it, their indexes will be `0`, `1`, `2`. `len(a)` gives you `3`. `i < len(a)` results in `0` through `2`.

You are also subtracting from `i` on the first iteration which is basically asking the compiler `if a[0] <= a[-1]` which results in `a[-1]` being outside of the boundaries of the array. You do so again with `a[i] <= a[i-2]`.

I'm fairly certain you just need something like:

```golang
func almostIncreasingSequence(a []int) bool {
    count := 0 // := is shorthand. So long as it is within a func it is basically equiv of var. It also infers the type.
    l :=  len(a) - 1
    for i := 0; i < l; i++ {
        if a[i] > a[i+1] {
            count++
        }
    }
    r := count <= 1
    fmt.Println(a, r)
    return r
}
```

Results in:

```
[1 3 2 1] false
[1 3 2] true
```

https://play.golang.org/p/8d_3a_PMM2C

If performance is important and the array could be large, add a check for count:

```golang
        if a[i] > a[i+1] {
            count = count + 1
            if(count > 1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The reason it worked in JavaScript is due to how `Undefined` is treated.

```js
console.log(1 < undefined)
console.log(0 < undefined)

const array = []

console.log(array[0] < 0)
console.log(array[-1] < 0)
console.log(array[9999] < 0)
```

It is an incredibly forgiving language due to the terrain it was devised for.